# VB.NET - Why does this sql command work as a string but not as a parameterized query?

Tags: sql, vb.net

```
Dim command_sbsp As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM SNOMED_ORG_INFO WHERE ConceptID=@ID AND Genus='SALMONELLA' AND SubSpecies=@Subsp", SNOMED_DB)

For Each match As Long In choices
 command_sbsp.Parameters.Clear()
 command_sbsp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Subsp", word)
 command_sbsp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", match)
```

The above doesn't work. The query attempt says there's nothing that matches that. But when I try it as a simple string concatenation, it works fine.

```
command_sbsp = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM SNOMED_ORG_INFO WHERE ConceptID=" + match.ToString + " AND Genus='SALMONELLA' AND SubSpecies='" + word + "'", SNOMED_DB)
```

Myself and a coworker have stared at this quite a lot and we can't figure out why it's not working. The problem is in the value for @ID (since it still works when I leave the other one parameterized). The funny thing is, Just a few lines of code above it I have a different query that sets a parameterized value for the same ID, using the the same choices list that the For Each loop is getting the match variable from.

Choices is a list of longs, and when I use choices(0) to parameterize ID in a query, it works. But now down here in this loop I have the new match long, and it doesn't want to make it work for me. Any thoughts?

Comment: What is the type of `match`? Does `command_sbsp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", match.ToString())` make any difference?

Comment: match as Long ... that's what the source states

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Despite the fact that the OLEDB class can use named parameters, it is actually just using a '?' marker in the background, so the parameters are in INDEX order.  Your sql has the ID variable occurring before the Subsp variable.

Switch it around, like so:

```
For Each match As Long In choices
 command_sbsp.Parameters.Clear()
 command_sbsp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", match)
 command_sbsp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Subsp", word)
```

Comment: Well that fixed it... what is the point of having variable names ID and Subsp if I still have to enter things in the order they appear in the query? Ah well, thanks a bunch for clearing that up.